# Beamer with Bibtex: References Bullet Formatted Incorrectly in Table of Contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, apa-style

I'm using beamer to make a presentation. I am also adding references with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. When I create a table of contents with `\tableofcontents`, the "References" shows up as the last section, as it should, but it has no number and is not formatted correctly. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[serif,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{Presentation}

\author{Author Author}
\institute {University}
\date{August 16, 2013}

\begin{document}

\frame[shrink=2]{\titlepage}
%==================================
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%==================================
\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Introduction
\end{frame}
%==================================
\section[Part 1]{Part 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Part 1}
Part 1 \\
\cite{ref2013}
\end{frame}
%==================================
\section[Conclusion]{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusion}
Conclusion
\end{frame}
%==================================
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Put this in the file ref.bib:

```
@article{ref2013,
    Author={Author, A.},
    Title={A very interesting paper},
    Journal={Great Journal},
    Volume={1},
    Pages={1--10},
    Year={2013} }
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the `numberedbib` option for `apacite`; this makes the bibliography to be treated as a `\section` and not as an unnumbered `\section*`:

```
\documentclass[serif,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Introduction
\end{frame}

\section[Part 1]{Part 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Part 1}
Part 1 \\
\cite{ref2013}
\end{frame}

\section[Conclusion]{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusion}
Conclusion
\end{frame}
\nocite{*}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]